# Can you explain this mysterious code?

Tags: c++

Found this while debugging C++ code in Embarcadero RAD Studio. It appears to compile, but frankly, while it seems obvious what it's meant to do, I can't figure out what it's actually doing.

```
TObject *objPtr ( new TObject() );
```

If anyone could offer a sane explanation, I would be grateful.

Comment: C++ lets you initialize built-in types (such as integers or pointers) with a syntax similar to object constructors. You can also use this constructor-like syntax as a typecast operation, e.g. `int foo = some_function(int(bar))`.

Comment: You need to read up on constructors (ctors). This uses a syntax that is specific to C++ that reflects how a ctor gets called, rather than the more usual an C-like syntax you may be used to. Usually you would see that not for pointers but rather for class instances that get created on the stack. Nice question, though. +1.

Comment: While all the answers are correct, and I thought of putting one such answer before any of these came along, the question as I read it was, **why** is it initializing a TObject (and not some descendent)? e.g. it is obvious it is doing what the answers say, but **what is the actual goal**?

Answer (score 4):

It's using direct initialization syntax to initialize `objPtr` to a newly allocated Tobject. For most practical purposes, it's equivalent to `Tobject *objPtr = new Tobject();`.

Answer (score 1):

This creates an object of type TObject on the heap and stores its location in a TObject pointer called objPtr.  It should be deleted via the line delete `objPtr` at some point to prevent memory leaks.